# How to upload a file in JavaScript that is in the browser cache?

Tags: javascript, php, image, google-chrome, upload

I am in a fix, as I have to put a file that has been dropped into a *DIV* widget (Google Chrome) to a server location. I can see the file created in the browser cache in a new window:

```
    var image = new Image();

    getBlobFromURL(blobURL).then(fromBlobToBase64).then(function(result) {
        image.src = result;

        var headerImageLocation = //'../Appbilder/Startseite/' +
            seldomID() + '.' + getFileExtension(result);
        var w = window.open('');

        w.document.write(image.outerHTML);

        fileUpload(image.outerHTML);
        …
    };
```

Although the image is there, I cannot upload it with following function I found in the Web:

```
function fileUpload(file) {
    var url = server.ServiceTest + 'images/';   // 'http://app.ivm.at/ServiceTest/images/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', url);
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('uploadfile', file);

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

What I need is to grab the visible file and send it to a specific server location. The code of the Web page is located somewhere called *./Backend*, and the image should go to the *./Backend/images* location. What do I wrong? Do I have to write the file locally first before being able to send it? The URL I send with *xhr.open* is the location where I want the file to be uploaded.

**EDIT 1:**
I want to save the file with a PHP code. Is this correct:

```
$formData = $_POST['formData'];

$fp = fopen($formData.filename, "w");

fwrite($fp, $formData.file);

fclose($fp);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I slightly modified the code as follows, as I have to try to find a solution while waiting:

```
fileUpload(image.src, headerImageLocation, url);
```

The method looks like this now:

```
function fileUpload(file, fileName, url) {
    var functionName = logging.createFunctionName('fileUpload', file, fileName, url);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    // den AJAX Request anlegen

    messages.print(functionName, 'called');
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('filename', fileName);  // Anhängen der Datei an das Objekt
    formData.append('file', file);  // Anhängen der Datei an das Objekt

    xhr.send(formData);
};
```

On the server side, I get created a file called 'filename' that contains four letters: 'file'. So, **we are approaching**. What I need is that the filename & the real content is passed so that I get a  on the server side (like 01237.png) and the right content.

**EDIT 3:** Trying to find a solution to my problem, I removed the *FormData* object, as I could not access the contents of it with PHP. I use now the following code on C/S side:

```
function fileUpload(file, fileName, url) {
    var functionName = logging.createFunctionName('fileUpload', file, fileName, url);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    // den AJAX Request anlegen

    messages.print(functionName, 'called');
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    var data = { name: fileName, image: file};

    xhr.send(data);
};
```

On the server side, I access the data with the following PHP code:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];

$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Only proceed if we got valid input
if ($data !== null) {
    //$fp = fopen('filename', "w");
    $fp = fopen($data->name, "w");

    fwrite($fp, $data->image);
    //fwrite($fp, 'image');

    fclose($fp);
} else {
    $result = 'Nothing posted';
}

die(json_encode($result));
```

I left the two commented lines that would create a file called 'filename' with the content 'image'. The uncommented part does neither give an error, nor does it create anything in the current directory.

Till now all my server access was with PHP code that called the database. I am writing the first service that tries to create directly a file on the server side.

Comment: You have to write server side code to process the POST request. (Explaining how to do that in detail to too broad for SO)

Comment: Thank you! How to send an unsaved file to the server side so that the (PHP) code to be written there can access it? Has the file to be saved locally first?

Comment: You use the code you've already written.

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin! But on the server side, how can I save the file? I wrote the PHP code you can see in the edit above.

Comment: There's no edit with PHP in it.

Comment: Sorry, but now, there is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154696/discussion-between-sae1962-and-quentin).